# How can I set the order on a Rails collection fetched using Model.uniq.pluck(:field)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm collecting the sale_stage of a group of Questions for display in my rails app view - which works fine provided I want them in alphabetical order (I don't):

```
@stages = Question.uniq.pluck(:sale_stage)
```

What I want is to select the same unique sale_stage names, but order them by question_id - as this would then display the stages in the right order on my page. I've tried using:

```
@stages = Question.order(:id).uniq.pluck(:sale_stage)
```

But this throws the following error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "questions"."sale_stage" FROM "questions"   ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC
PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...estions"."sale_stage" FROM "questions"   ORDER BY "questions...
                                                         ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "questions"."sale_stage" FROM "questions"   ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 251ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...estions"."sale_stage" FROM "questions"   ORDER BY "questions...
                                                         ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "questions"."sale_stage" FROM "questions"   ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC):
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means - and the answer for this StatementInvalid error don't help me much. Can anyone advise how to order this query by question_id please?

Comment: Interesting, in the SELECT DISTINCT you'd need the id in order to be able to order by id. Just a side-note, you won't need the `uniq` at all.
You might have succes with this one: `Question.order(:id).to_a.pluck(:sale_stage)`

Comment: Try this: `@stages = Question.order(:id).pluck(:sale_stage).uniq`

Comment: Thanks Vishal - that works. If you put it as an answer I'll select it as the correct one.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@stages = Question.order(:id).pluck(:sale_stage).uniq
```